# Split string separated by comma in a batch file and call a sqlplus function in the loop

Tags: sql, batch-file, split, scripting, sqlplus

I'm trying to split a String separated by comma and then call a function of sql with each splitted strings. The length of strings to split is variable.

I have this code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set CCVs="0008123123,000815432123"
for /F "delims=," %%a in ("%CCVs%") do (
    SQLPLUS -S -L %DBCONN% @%~dp0generate.sql %%a
)
```

But I see that the loop call the SQLPLUS function with the param "0008123123 000815432123" not two times one with string 0008123123 and a second time 000815432123

Comment: I'd advise you to define your variable like this `set "CCVs=0008123123,000815432123"`, in order that you've not included unnecessary double-quotes within its value data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a standard FOR command. Also do not get in the habit of assigning quotes to your variables.  That is bad practice in regards to coding batch files. It is a best practice though to use them to surround the assignment to protect special characters and from trailing spaces getting assigned to the value.

```
@echo off
set "CCVs=0008123123,000815432123"
for %%a in (%CCVs%) do (
    SQLPLUS -S -L %DBCONN% @%~dp0generate.sql %%a
)
```